# Connect vpn when domain matches and disconnect VPN when rule doesn't match in iOS VPN on Demand rule

Tags: ios, swift, vpn

I am trying to establish on demand VPN. If user enter domain *.example.com, vpn should connect and for any other domain, VPN should disconnect. From the code below, VPN is starting on domain match but VPN is not disconnecting for other domain. Is this requirement possible to achieve?

```
<key>OnDemandEnabled</key>
                <integer>1</integer>
                <key>OnDemandRules</key>
                <array>
                    <dict>
                        <key>Action</key>
                        <string>EvaluateConnection</string>
                        <key>ActionParameters</key>
                        <array>
                            <dict>
                                <key>DomainAction</key>
                                <string>ConnectIfNeeded</string>
                                <key>Domains</key>
                                <array>
                                    <string>*.example.com</string>
                                </array>
                            </dict>
                        </array>
                    </dict>
                    <dict>
                        <key>Action</key>
                        <string>Ignore</string>
                    </dict>
                </array>
```